# Rebol url? function doesn't really detect url?

Tags: rebol

I want to read the clipboard, if it's an url do some stuff. Problem is url? doesn't do the job as:

```
url? to-url "any string" will return true
```

Is this normal ? How do I do the detection I want then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**to-url** makes a string into a REBOL datatype of URL!

What you want is to detect if a string conforms to the rules for a URL. That is nor easy or fool proof as many strings can be URLs in the real world, eg:

- http://xxx
- ftp://xxx
- ## frag
- cgi-bin/script.php

If you want to capture the more common cases (eg those that start with **http://**, **https://** etc), then consider using **parse**.

This script **almost does the job**:
[link text](http://www.rebol.org/view-script.r?script=uri.r)

What it missing is some charset definitions (I think the code must have been hurriedly cut'n'pasted from somewhere else)....

```
alpha: charset [#"a" -  #"z" #"A" - #"Z"]
digits: charset [#"0" - #"9"]
alphadigit: union alpha digits
```

...and an example of how to use it: Assuming you have saved it locally as uri.r:

```
url-parse: do %uri.r
parse "http://sss" parse-url/url
== true
parse "sss" parse-url/url
== false
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
url? load "any://string"`
```

or

```
url? attempt [load "any string"]
```

To use REBOL's definition of a URL.